# Bootstrap Tooltip Not working with aria-describedby

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I didn`t understand why my bootstrap tooltip not work.
    when i add title attributes to element and hover on it, title attributes set to null and add one other element call area-describedby.

```
<button id="test" type="button" class="btn_primary" title="" aria-describedby="ui-tooltip-5">Tooltip on left</button>
<div id="ui-tooltip-3" role="tooltip" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-widget-content" style="position: relative; top: -5px; left: 0px; display: block;"><div class="ui-tooltip-content">Tooltip on left</div></div>
```

I compared with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/31/

Any idea why this is happening?

```
i am currently use this bootstrap and jquery version
Bootstrap v3.3.4
jQuery v2.1.4
jQuery UI - v1.11.2 - 2014-10-16
```

Comment: You should also post the javascript and html code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the solution,

> use jquery-ui.min.js before bootstrap.min.js

This error occured to conflict 2 js file..

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it, but I could not understand. I set a breakpoint on that jquery function (with all the buttons), but I could not trigger those breakpoints. Somehow watching at the DOM I have noticed that those buttons have some event handlers, some of the more interesting are `mouseover`. Which I think are the one triggering the .tooltip() function. They add some div to the page, but i need to solve this later. So I am posting this message as a memo.

Thanks 
Fabrizio
[image]

Comment: i got reason of problem but don't know how to solve. 
I use Bootstrap and jquery-ui both together that's why tooltip not display..
if u have any solution please tell me.
Thank's kaushik :)

Comment: if i comment jquery.ui from my page it's work.. but with jquery.ui it's not

Comment: @Kaushiksolanki sorry i tried to find a solution. I can not figure out. I am not so expert with jquery. I tried with `.mouseover()` but it does not work, the `.tooltip()` effect comes from `bootstrap.min.js`. The event triggered is at line 502 of `jquery-3.1.1.js `. This function get called allways. I think that tooltip does not come from your code, but from the jquery code. If you set a breakpoint there, it is called on mouse over while it is not in your javascript code.

Comment: It's okay dear, i got thesolution and post my answer.
thank's for your kind response :)